# Is it possible to save an object with WP Customizer?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an option which is saved into the database as an object.
For example:

```
$obj->attr1 = 'foo';
$obj->attr2 = 'foo';
update_option('foo', $obj);
```

Is it possible to do something similar with WP Customizer? At this moment i've only seen examples of how to save simple string values. Does the control/settings allow us to do something similar?

At this moment I had to break the object into two settings like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('foo-attr1', array(
    'default' => get_option('foo-attr1'),
    'type' => 'option',
    'capability' => 'manage_options'
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('foo-attr2', array(
    'default' => get_option('foo-attr2'),
    'type' => 'option',
    'capability' => 'manage_options'
));
```

Comment: Because you have to define unique ID('foo-attr1' and 'foo-attr2' in this case) to each setting its recommended to add it manually. If you still want to reduce a bit then create a array and loop through it would be a good way out.

Comment: It's not possible to unify the settings into a single one then?